# Is a transit visa required for an Indian in a connecting flight via USA coming from Toronto?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival

I am an Indian studying in Toronto, returning to India via USA in a connecting flight. Do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Indian citizens require a visa for the US, no matter how long or whether it's just a connecting flight.

Some countries can use the Visa Waiver Program, while others, including India, need to apply for a visa (source: [US Department of State](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit.html)).

For information on applying for a visa, I recommend having a look at [Immigroup's page on US visas](http://www.immigroup.com/us-visa-appointments).

More info on who needs or doesn't need visas for transit or visiting the US: [WorldTravelGuide's page on the USA](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/united-states-america/passport-visa).

Comment: Since there is a $160 nonrefundable fee to apply for a US visa, and no guarantee it will actually be issued, it may be cheaper and easier to change the flight to one that connects in some other country.