# Do I need a transit visa for the USA for travelling to Toronto via Newark?

Tags: usa, airports

I am an Indian national. I am flying from New Delhi to Toronto with United Airlines via Newark. I will be landing at terminal C Newark Liberty airport with a transit time of 3 hours 55 minutes and then I have a connecting flight to Toronto from Terminal B La Guardia New York with the same United Airlines. Do I need a transit visa for the USA? More related information would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the airline provide transportation from Newark to LaGuardia, or do you have to manage it yourself?  It could be challenging for a newcomer, and 3:55 is really not that much time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Indian nationals require a transit visa for the US. See this answer [Is a transit visa required for an Indian in a connecting flight via USA coming from Toronto?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39819/is-a-transit-visa-required-for-an-indian-in-a-connecting-flight-via-usa-coming-f/39820#39820)
 And https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html